# android ram free up/ garbage collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, ram

All,

I would like to free up ram on my android for a data intensive operation and also be able to free up ram when the user wants to. The first thing I thought of doing was running system.gc(). However, that is not a guarantee that the garbage collector will work. Any suggestions on how to immediately and guarantee that ram is freed up when the code is called.? Also, how do the apps that free up ram when you click a widget accomplish this task?

I guess a better way to phrase this is: How do I manually free up memory like the Android OS?

Thx

Comment: What if there's no garbage? You can only release memory that is not referenced anymore. Such a guarantee cannot exist (and the weaker form is still a huge restriction on the VM, which ultimately lowers efficency).

Comment: The vm frees RAM when it is needed. Thus, for all intents and purposes, all memory not allocated to live objects is always available. I doubt very much that your operation or users would receive any appreciable benefit from accomplishing this (if it's possible at all).

Comment: So here is the thing. I have an app that I call system.gc() in an attempt to free up ram. Usually nothing happens, but then I click on a widget of another app that frees ram and I see a 100% increase in free ram and an increase in UI responsiveness.

Comment: @jib, answered that question in an edit to my answer below

Comment: @Andrew . When you are manipulating a bitmap that is not the case. You will run out of memory and force close. However, manually free up ram you can run without any problems. So a better question then is how do I manually free up ram like the OS does. Thx.

Comment: @jib I'm not sure; the official line is that it hasn't been necessary to do that since the very early versions of Android, if then. You could read up on how to send signals to other processes, but I think you'd have better luck trying to find out why your program is not considered important enough by the OS to cause it to force-close other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do this. Android will kill lower priorized apps to free memory  if you need more than currently available.

Comment: Ok so how to the so called free memory apps do this then? There is a clear change in free ram and an increase in UI responsiveness.

Comment: They just kill processes. But as I said, you actually don't have to do this manually because Android will do it for you as soon as memory gets rare.

Comment: When you are manipulating a bitmap that is not the case. You will run out of memory and force close. However, manually free up ram you can run without any problems. So a better question then is how do I manually free up ram like the OS does. Thx

Comment: if your app needs so much mem it gets killed, I guess the only right option is optimizing this memory-hungry process somehow instead of killing other apps. Otherwise, it'll likely go oom on older devices with not so much ram.

Comment: Well what if you want to create an app that frees ram. There are times that this is helpful to make the UI more responsive before the garbage collector executes.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the theory on Android is that running applications should relinquish memory through a callback mechanism when another process with higher priority (i.e., the current foreground process) needs more memory; additionally, the OS will start killing other applications if memory demands increase further.

Therefore, if you want your application to be able to use substantially all of the system's memory, you just need to make sure it stays in the foreground or use some other mechanism to ensure that its memory demands are higher priority than other memory demands (unfortunately, I couldn't say what that latter part would look like exactly).

There's not really much you can or should do manually to free up memory outside of your specific application.  The OS is doing the right thing: as memory is needed, it tells applications "delete all non-essential data" and then after that if more memory is needed it tells them to get lost.  Any manual approach to freeing up memory would basically do the same thing.

Edit: It sounds like you are wondering what other "memory-freeing" applications are doing.  The answer is, they're taking the manual approach and doing the same thing the OS does -- sending signals to running processes.  The reason this is unnecessary is that free ram doesn't actually do you any good before you need it.  The OS will do this right before you need the extra space, which ensures no processes are killed before absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a garbage collector. iOS does not.

Comment: But the actual version of the compiler for iOS apps has: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/ (Automatic Reference Counting)